# SQL + Core Data in Swift

Tags: python, sql, swift, core-data

So my initial question was concerning the strange output I was getting when running a SQL statement on a db on the phone (running iOS 12).

I was writing and testing my SQL statements in DB Browser for SQLite, but when I then executed these same statements in the simulator I was getting a single value when requesting weekly averages. I recently also tested these same commands in Python, and got a similar/strange result, leading me to suspect it is due to the strftime command. Can I use this command with Swift or Python and if not is it due to the specifier syntax?

Here is a sample SQL statement:
SELECT AVG(ZAMOUNT) FROM ZCATH GROUP BY strftime('%w', ZTIMESTAMP)

Comment: So is this really a question about grouping in SQLite?

Comment: Not entirely, of the 10 SQL statements I have written only 5 of them involve grouping. I guess my real question is I am not sure why the SQL executes differently in DB Browser than it does in Swift. I have edited my initial question with some sample code. Thanks!